# Create version wise dir inside gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Am using gitlab cicd and my runners are mostly win and linux
When I push my code to gitlab the cicd pipeline is triggered and the files get stored in this gitlab-runner folder

This is my gitlab yaml file:

```
variables:
  GIT_CLONE_PATH: ${CI_BUILDS_DIR}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}


stages:
  - Run

CLI:
  tags:
    - windows-pc
  stage: Run
  script:
      - echo "hello"
```

Now I have a script which gives the version of the code in form of string say V_1_1_0.

I want to run this script inside the yml file and add the version number string to the GIT_CLONE_PATH, so that the files get cloned inside that specific version folder.